# Set a twig variable from an external JS file

Tags: javascript, typescript, twig

I want to set the value of my twig variable from an external js file.

I have this code in twig:

```
{% set items = null }
{% include "list.twig" with { itemList: items} %}
```

And I want to set the items from an external Js. How can I update the value of the items from Js ?

Comment: That's not possible: Twig is running on the server, JS in your browser. You could refactor your application to write this list using JS

Comment: Related: [Difference between client- and serverside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)